# Bootstrap navigation with prettyPhoto doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, prettyphoto

have a problem and I hope somebody helps me.
Have website 3gtrans.sk in bootstrap. It works fine but mobile navigation doesn't work on 2 pages

https://www.3gtrans.sk/nase-trasy

https://www.3gtrans.sk/galeria

As you can see on that pages are some photos (prettyPhoto). Can anybody show me what is bad please? Thank you so much.

i.e. galeria.php

```
<?php include "xxx.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Galéria | 3G Trans Slovakia" />
    <meta name="author" content="RoyalWEB.sk" />

    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css?<?php echo date('h:i:s'); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%7CRaleway">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet"/>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Galéria | 3G Trans Slovakia</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                show_title: false,
                social_tools: false
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mynavbar" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                    <li><a href="/">o nás</a></li>
                  <li><a href="nase-trasy">naše trasy</a></li>
                  <li><a href="referencie">referencie</a></li>
                  <li><a href="objednat-prepravu">objednať prepravu</a></li>
                  <li><a class="active" href="galeria">galéria</a></li>
                  <li><a href="kontakt">kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="container wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Galéria</h1>
                <p>
                    <a href="images/gallery/peugeot01.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery/thumb_peugeot01.jpg" alt="Peugeot Travel" /> <a href="images/gallery/peugeot02.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery/thumb_peugeot02.jpg" alt="Peugeot Travel" /></a>
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="container copyright">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Copyright &copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> | 3G Trans Slovakia<br />Vytvorila firma <a href="https://www.royalweb.sk">RoyalWEB.sk</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-101095120-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.9/cookieconsent.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"Táto stránka využíva súbory cookies, ktoré pomáhajú k jeho správnemu fungovaniu. Využívaním našich služieb s ich používaním súhlasíte.","dismiss":"Rozumiem","learnMore":"Viac informácií","link":"https://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie","theme":"light-bottom"};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed with replacing prettyphoto for another plugin.